# pytorch spyder variable explorer break

Tags: python, pytorch, spyder

[image]the line `x=torch.from_numpy(x)` which x is a numpy array at first, causes the spyder variable explorer to break. after that the no variable can be added to variable explorer eventhough they are usable. do you know any way to avoid this? I was using 5.0.2 and hadn't this problem but it appeared I don't know why, and upgraded spyder to 5.0.3 by windows installer and problem yet exists. or if you are using spyder please try and comment do you face the same problem? and I should say there is no error just a bug report pop up.

Comment: what you mean by "just a bug report pop up"?

Comment: an window to report bug.

Comment: does it have any particular message? this usually indicates that something wrong happened

Comment: @Berriel "spyder has encountered an interal problem"!! I can't send pics in comments.
btw I noticed your are using spyder and pytorch, do you face same problem? can you check?

Comment: Update the question with an image of the pop-up. That might be helpful. I don't actually use spyder, so I cannot reproduce it =[

Comment: @Berriel right my bad. and I just edited question.